# Full screen HTML5 Video

Tags: css, html, video, html5-video

I've looked all over and have not found a great solution yet. I am trying to implement a full screen, responsive video. Here is the specific structure of the site.

Fixed header

Masthead - Has full screen video

Main - 5 sub sections, all full screen

Footer

so, the Masthead is a div that contains some text and the video itself that is designed to take up 100% of the width and height of the screen. This div needs to be responsive and scale with the page.

Currently, I have a solution that fills the page, but expands beyond the height of the page when it gets too wide, which is not ideal. Does anyone have a solution for this?

I've looked at the "full screen background video" links, but those actually treat it as a page background and fix the video to the viewport, which is not what needs to happen here.

Here is my code.

HTML

```
<div id="masthead">
    <div class="masthead-intro">
        <h1>We are a Community for Good</h1>
        <h3>Curabitur dignissim elemen tum ante pellentesque rhoncus.<br>
        Viva muse rutrum felis id risus tris tique, ut congue orci.</h3>
    </div>

    <video src="/video/PCL_BornDreamersShortForm.mp4" poster="img/masthead-video.png" autoplay loop muted></video>
</div>
```

And CSS

```
#masthead {
margin-top: $baseline*3;
position: relative;
margin-bottom: $mobile-baseline*3;
max-height: 100vh;
@include respond-to-min($break-medium) {
    margin-bottom: $baseline*3;
    margin-top: 0;
}

video {     
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -100;
    overflow: hidden;
}
}
```

I am not opposed to a jquery or javascript solution if anybody has one.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the video expands beyond the height of the page since you are setting height to auto and this overrides the previous `height:100%`. What about doing it the other way around?

```
video {     
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    z-index: -100;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Of course, this would have the problem that in displays where the width is bigger than the height, there will be an area not covered by the video. Perhaps you can edit two versions of the video, one for vertical and one for horizontal displays and load the appropriate one with an @media query in css or with jquery.